Does Linux fork even copy registers?
I recently learned that fork applies COW (copy on write) even on registers.
I played with a simple toy case to verify:
(gdb) info inferiors
  Num  Description       Connection           Executable
* 1    process 59316     1 (native)           /home/Drew/mycode/a.out
  2    process 59386     1 (native)           /home/Drew/mycode/a.out
(gdb) print( $rdi )
$1 = 18874385
(gdb) set $rdi=42
(gdb) print( $rdi )
$2 = 42
(gdb) inferior 2
[Switching to inferior 2 [process 59386] (/home/Drew/mycode/a.out)]
[Switching to thread 2.1 (process 59386)]
#0  0x00002aaaab090291 in fork () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) print( $rdi )
$3 = 18874385

As you guys see, modifying rdi in parent proc does not interfere child proc.
I wonder how is it done? does modern CPU provides multiple same registers exclusively for multi-process?
EDIT:
Thanks to you fellows for commenting. I'll answer the questions in comments here collectively, hope it helps clarify.
The reference I'm using is this lecture note.
I generally want to figure out:

Does Linux ever copy, no matter COW or not, the registers?
If the answer is yes, is it done by HW, i.e., CPU manufactures provides design support like they do for supporting virtual machine, or by SW, say, OS stores the register value somewhere (in RAM?), so, instead of operating on the registers themselves, it effectively modifies page but somehow managed to mimic the register behavior?
If fork does not copy registers by any means, why am I seeing the phenomenon in GDB?


It doesn't apply copy on write, it just copies the register values. Each process (and thread) has its own copy of the registers which is read/written to memory on task switch.

I don't think COW exists for registers. Where did you learn that it does that?

There are cases where copy-on-write could be considered to apply to registers. Some processors partition some subsets of registers, such as floating-point or vector registers. A thread can run with access to the general registers but trap when it tries to use one of the other register subsets, at which point the kernel can save (copy) the register contents. But, for a proper answer, you would have to cite a source for this statement and its context.

COW or not, you weren't expecting a modification of a register on a parent process, after it has spawned its child to have effect in the child, were you? What would be the point of having different process, if they are doomed to have identical registers for life, therefore doing the exact same computation? Process switching, generally speaking (whether ensure by the hardware, or by the OS) ensure that each process can work on their own private (or seemingly private) registers, without worrying about what other process do.

Your question is not clear to me but it seems like somewhere you have misunderstanding about fork(). fork() is not about copying registers, fork() simply allocates process struct and exec() uses to load the binary. During the execution of the process instructions get loaded in the registers while CPU execute.

Where in the referenced document do you see that the registers are subject to COW?

Please [edit] your question to elaborate on your "problem" about writing and reading of registers to/from RAM while switching tasks? Why should a processor not have instructions to do this?

If a process saves its registers on the stack and then forks, the new process will restore from its copy of the stack.

Are you familiar with the general concept of context switching?  This is how multitasking OSes provide the illusion that every process and thread has its own set of registers, despite there only actually being a single set of registers in the hardware.  Or is that something that you would like the answer to explain as well?

@thebusybee, I dont have a problem about the R/W to registers while switching tasks, in fact that is one of my assumption, I just want someone could help confirm and give some more details.

@NateEldredge, thanks for you guys' teaching which really helps clarify, yeah I guess the answer I am looking for is the virtualization scheme for registers and hopefully any other related ones.

Systems that provide pre-emptive multi-tasking provide CPU virtualization. This allows each thread to behave as if it has a CPU core (and its registers) to itself. More specifically, this allows a thread to use registers without having to worry about them getting changed by another thread (of the same process or a different one) in the middle of an operation.
This is the case no matter how the thread is created, and thus includes threads created by fork. How the system achieves this is not relevant. But it ensures that any changes to, say, rdi or the instruction pointer in one thread isn't seen in another.
I don't know what guarantees fork provides about the initial value of registers after a fork. It could be the same guarantees as other calls covered by the system's ABI.

Thanks mate, now I get that register sets are unique, so it is OS software that does a virtualization/multiplexing on the resources such as registers so that each process has its own registers, correct? Guess I'll go on trying to search for the implementation details, any further teaching or reference will be greatly appreciated.

And for CPU which really has multi-core, I guess it would be a mix of physical multiplexing and virtualization multiplexing.

"It could be the same guarantees as other calls covered by the system's ABI." It is. It's execve() that's the oddball in modern kernels. In old enough kernels it was just the ABI and we could smuggle extra integer arguments in call-preserved registers.

Fun fact: I once made a little program that didn't use copy on write at all, after spawning a child process they were the same except for registers and file handles.
It's actually pretty easy, just don't write to RAM at all.
Looking at the man page for clone(), we can even share RAM between parent and child. We can pass CLONE_VM but not CLONE_PID to accomplish this.
Register copy happens exactly once, when you create a new thread with fork(), vfork(), or clone() system calls.
Every process, every thread must inherently have a separate register bank; this is inherent in what it is to be a process (in the old terminology) or a thread (in the new terminology).
So how is this done?
Whenever the kernel switches threads, the old register bank is stored in the process data structure. (Remember the thing about terminology; the kernel uses the old terminology.) Whenever it switches back, it restores them. There's actually a little bit more to it; the process data structure actually has the kernel's register bank; the userspace register bank got pushed onto the kernel stack for the thread when the interrupt happened that triggered the context switch.
